# Using 2-legged OAuth with Google Tasks API in Java

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-tasks-api

I’m trying  to build a Sync application for Google Task API using Java.
An additional constraint I have is to use 2-legged OAuth.
I followed the article [Using 2-legged OAuth with Google Tasks API for Google Apps domain administrators](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/articles/2lo-in-tasks-for-admins) but the code sample they provided for Java doesn’t compile with the latest API libraries.

Also, there is lot of material available about Google Tasks, but either its deprecated or using non existent API/references.
It would be great help if someone could point me to a relevant article or working example.

Articles and sites I referred to:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the constraint to use 2LO? There are ways to write sync apps that use OAuth2 and tokens, which has more current library and sample support. You can request "offline" access and save the refresh token in the client. Then you can continually sync that data for the user in question. Is the reason you need 2LO that you need to do this for an entire domain of users without prompting them?

In any case, the tasks api and 2LO should be compatible even if you're having issues with some libraries. I can't comment on the state of all the samples and libraries, but if you follow the steps to approve the tasks api scope for your client_id in ManageOAuthClients and you know the ids of your domain users, and you sign your requests properly, it should 'just work'